# Dynamically creating Divs with Panels results in strangeness

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

What I do:

```
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Attributes["class"] = "resultview";

foreach (string st in summary)
{
    Panel answerPanel = new Panel();
    Label answerLbl = new Label();
    answerLbl.Text = theAnswer;
    answerPanel.Controls.Add(answerLbl);
    answerPanel.Attributes["class"] = "answer";
    //answerPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(theAnswer)); //Also tried this instead of a label
    p.Controls.Add(answerPanel);
}
```

What I get after two loops:

```
<div class="resultview">
    <div class="answer">
        <span>
            <div class="ExternalClass10FA632A5FA34598A2540E2A29E38841">Yes</div>
            <div class="answer"><span>No</span></div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want after two loops:

```
<div class="resultview">
    <div class="answer"><span>Yes</span></div>
    <div class="answer"><span>No</span></div>
</div>
```

So my question is why does the second "`div class=answer`" become nested in the first. And why is there a "`div class="ExternalClass...`"? And more importantly, what do I do to make look like I intended?

Comment: Why are you using `Label`s when they're not labeling anything?

Comment: Generaly i suggest you to create through DHTML on the apx page. I use it for years and i am very satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have mentioned this was a Sharepoint project. The solution is this:

http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/externalclass-enhanced-rich-text-fields-7091.aspx

...and more explained here:
http://www.sp-blogs.com/blogs/adnan/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15.

I.E: Sharepoint adds "div class="ExternalClass[GUID]"" to the beginning of list items when the list has 'enhanced rich text' selected as text type in its columns. You get rid of this with the regex: Regex.Replace(currentItem["Your Field Name"].ToString(), "<.*?>", string.Empty);